# tone analyzer api cannot be connected

Tags: ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I was trying to connect to Tone Analyzer through its API. I have created credentials on Bluemix as followes:

```
ta_url = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer-experimental/api/v2/profile"
username =  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
password = "yyyyyyyyyy"
```

I am able to connect to Personality Insight using the same method (the credentials are created separately).

Your kind help will be appreciated!

Best regards,
Ken

Comment: Ken, could you please add the piece of code that is failing and the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

[Tone Analyzer](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/tone-analyzer.html) and [Personality Insights](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/personality-insights.html) are two different services.
Looking at the url you are trying to use:

```
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer-experimental/api/v2/profile
```

I would guess that you are trying to use the `/tone` call which analyzes the "tone" of a piece of text.

The correct url should be:

```
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer-beta/api/v3/tone
```

#### Example Curl request

```
curl -X POST \
 -u USERNAME:PASSWORD \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d 'This is an important email. You should be working on X and have it ready by Friday' \
 "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer-experimental/api/v3/tone?version=2016-02-11"
```

Make sure you replace `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` with your service credentials.

---

See the [Tone Analyzer documentation](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/tone-analyzer.html) to read more about the service.
See [API Explorer](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/tone-analyzer/api/v3/) to learn more about the API.

Update: Tone Analyzer is now Beta; URLs have been corrected.